# In an AWS CloudFormation template, how can I tag an EC2 instance with it's own Id without getting circular reference errors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I've specified an EC2 instance in my CloudFormation template, and I want to tag it with it's own InstanceId, like so:

```
"Resources": {
    "myInstance": {
        ...
        "Tags": [
            { "Key": "instance.id", "Value": { "Ref": "myInstance" } },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

But trying to create a stack from this template generates a `AmazonCloudFormationException`: **"Circular dependency between resources: [myInstance]"**

Running instances and tagging them using the EC2 API is very straightforward:

```
//this is C#, but that's not significant

var instance = ec2Client.RunInstances(...) ...;
var id = instance.InstanceId;
ec2Client.CreateTags(new CreateTagRequest
{
    Resources = { id },
    Tags = { new Tag { Key = "instance.id", Value = id } }
});
```

This approach arises naturally from the fact that instance tags cannot be created as part of the `RunInstances` operation, so *all* tags, not just the self-identifier, must be applied in a subsequent API operation.

So... can I accomplish the same thing using CloudFormation? Thanks very much!

[(cross-posted to the AWS Forums)](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=180491)

Comment: What is the purpose of this tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can. CloudFormation only lets you tag a resource at creation time, and the value of the tag you want doesn't exist until the resource is created.

But I don't think this has to be a problem. The two use cases I can think of for tags are looking at an instance and seeing the tag values, or finding instances with certain tag values. You can see or find by instance-id without having a tag containing it.

Answer (score 4):

You can always create a startup script which will update the tag of the instance after the startup. You can use the following (AWS CLI):

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources `wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id` --tags Key=id,Value=`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
```

However, if you only want to use the instance id inside your application, you can use `wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id` to fetch the instance id.